How to understand pinout diagram of STM32 micro controllers
I am new to embedded systems. I started with arduino and learnt programming online and have done some projects with it as well. Now I bought STM32 nucleo board to learn more in embedded systems. I learnt blinking led and other basic programming using IDE. Now when its time to interface other sensors, lcd's etc, I got confused with outputs.
With arduino the I/O is pretty straight forward. With STM32 after setting GPIO pins as output in IDE (for eg PA0 - PA4)  I am not sure where is PA0-PA4 in STM32 nucleo F446  board. I tried online, youtube videos etc. I am getting more confused.
As a complete beginner, where should I start on how to understand the pin out diagrams and related stuff?
I tried youtube videos and other websites.

I'd try with the docs: https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/documentation.html

Youtube videos are one of the last resources you should consume. Start with the data sheet and the user manual of the Nucleo board, expecting tables and schematics, followed by the data sheet and user manual of the MCU. You will not ask some stranger how to operate your mobile, will you?

Cortex M micros usually come with needlessly complicated ways of enabling GPIO. There's often some manner of more or less advanced peripheral routing registers you must set first. Perhaps you must route a clock to it as well All this overhead is really tiresome to work with even for veterans.

When you are working with a Nucleo board, you should start with the Board User Manual for the Nucleo board.  Here is a Nucleo-64 User Manual that covers the F446 and other boards.  Review the entire Nucleo-64 User Manual.  And for your F446 board, look at Figure 25, Table 19, and Table 29 to know which microcontroller pins are connected to which board connector pins.  Notice that this User Manual covers multiple boards and the connector pins may vary between boards.  You might also want to search for the schematic for your board if the schematic isn't included in the user manual.
When you are working with a custom board or you want to know the function of each microcontroller pin, then read the Microcontroller Datasheet.  Here is the STM32F446 Datasheet.  Review the entire datasheet.  But look at Table 10, "pin and ball descriptions", to know the functions of each pin.  Notice that there are multiple different packages such as 64-pin, 100-pin, and 144-pin packages.  The pin numbers can vary between packages but the table covers them all.
Then to know how to control the pins and the peripherals you need to refer to the Microcontroller Reference Manual for your microcontroller.
